# Does the left shift operator, as defined here, satisfy an analogue of the product rule, and if so, what?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, differential-operators

Define the left shift operator as follows:

$$\lambda_x y = \frac{y-(x:=0)y}{x}$$

where $(x:= 0)$ means "replace every copy of $x$ by $0$," or equivalently "evaluation at $0$."

For example,

$$\lambda_x(1+3x-x^2) = \frac{1+3x-x^2-(1+3\cdot 0-0^2)}{x} = 3-x.$$

For comparison, lets compute the derivative, too:

$$\partial_x(1+3x-x^2) = 3-2x.$$

So when $\lambda_x$ is applied to a power series, the constant term is dropped, and the whole series shifts to the left; similar to how differentiation works, except that $\partial_x$ also introduces a modification to the coefficients equal to the exponent of the relevant term.

Now it's clear that $\lambda_x$ is linear. And, given that $\lambda_x$ is similar to $\partial_x$, we might expect some kind of product rule to hold. But I've been staring at the expression $$\lambda_x(y\cdot z)$$ for awhile, and I'm not seeing anything.

> **Question.** Does the left shift operator, as defined here, satisfy an analogue of the product rule, and if so, what?

Comment: This is actually distantly related to my dissertation (it was a Leibniz formula for operators that are formally similar to the derivative).

Comment: Just to be clear, $\lambda_x y(x) = (y(x) - y(0))/x$? And the "$x$" in $\lambda_x$ does not actually mean that there is an operator $\lambda_x$ for each $x$ (so it should probably be called $\lambda$ or something else instead)?

Comment: If $y$ is a function of $x$, then you might try writing $$\lambda_{x} (y) = \frac{y(x) - y(0)}{x}$$

Comment: @AJY it's only guaranteed to have an associated function when for $x=0$. Otherwise it may not converge. So arguably it doesn't make sense to use function notation.

Comment: @MattSamuel Should "when for $x = 0$" say "for $x \neq 0$?

Comment: @Ajy No. What I mean more succinctly is that zero is the only value you can plug in.

Comment: @MattSamuel how so? I'm really not understanding your comment at all.

Comment: @AJY The left shift operator makes sense for any infinite sequence of coefficients. You can write this sequence as a formal power series and they behave as you'd expect. But it's purely formal; we're not considering the sum off the series at all, because it may not exist, but it doesn't matter if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MattSamuel The OP doesn't seem to be defining what she deems the "left shift operator" on any kind of sequential space, as might be standard, but as an operator on functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)g(x)-f(0)g(0)=(f(x)-f(0))g(x)+f(0)(g(x)-g(0))$$
Thus your left shift operator satisfies the Leibniz formula
$$\lambda_x(yz)=(\lambda_xy)z+((x:=0)y)(\lambda_xz)$$